# Unable to get desired results using bootstrap 4. Need to know what i am doing wrong?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap grid, i am unable to get the desired outcome. I have four divs with classes col-sm-3 and as per rule all 4 should display in one line as it is 12 column layout. But it's not. I have also attached the screenshots

Already tried other breakpoints too like xs and md

```
<div class="testing container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box1 justify-content-center col-xs-3 col-lg-6">BOX 1</div>
            <div class="box2 col-xs-3 col-lg-6">BOX 2</div>
            <div class="box3 col-xs-3 col-lg-6">BOX 3</div>
            <div class="box4 col-xs-3 col-lg-6">BOX 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>

In mobile devices all boxes should be in one line
```

Comment: Are you able to post any css that would accompany your post.
Also Bootstrap 4 changed col-xs-3 to just col-3

Comment: @DylanAnlezark well that’s solved the issue. Col-3 class is working

Comment: Great :) i will make an answer if you could accept it as the solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has changed its col-xs class it is now just col- and then the size of the column you want for example:
col-1 col-2 col-3
Note that col-smm col-md and col-lg still work in the way they did in bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Don't use xs in BS4. use sm for anything under 576px.

```php
<div class="testing container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box1 justify-content-center col-3 col-sm-6">BOX 1</div>
            <div class="box2 col-3 col-sm-6">BOX 2</div>
            <div class="box3 col-3 col-sm-6">BOX 3</div>
            <div class="box4 col-3 col-sm-6">BOX 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```